# How should I integrate Sony Camera Add-on API with my application?

Tags: android, sony

I am developing an application that should only run in **sony xperia z2**. I have gone through all this API but could not find any good solution for it. It's fine to understand for theory but not for practicality. I have already been downloaded sony SDK from its official site and  integrated in Eclipse. But what code should be the right one to start with camera and play with AR effect. Can you please help me?

http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/tutorials/android_tutorial/create-augmented-reality-apps-with-wikitude-android-sdk-and-sonys-camera-add-on-api/

I wish to have some thing like this:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonymobile.androidapp.cameraaddon.areffect

Answer (score 1):

There is no code example of an AR effect Camera Add-on app in the Sony Add-on SDK.  To build an AR app I would recommend first learning how to build a Camera Add-on app, then after you have done that learn to add AR on top of that using the Wikitude SDK.

There is a code sample of how to build a Basic camera add-on app in the /samples folder of the Sony Add-on SDK.